# CONSTRAINT to restrict DUPLICATE values among 2 Columns

Tags: mysql, constraints, unique, multiple-columns

I need to put a constraint which will restrict DUPLICATE entries in combination of 2 columns.

So I have a customers table, with the below mentioned columns

id, first_name, last_name, date_of_birth, gender, email_address, primary_number, secondary_number.

What I am expecting is to have primary_number value unique for 2 columns. i.e. primary_number & secondary_number.

Eg.

| primary_number | secondary_number |
| --- | --- |
| 123456789 | 987654321 |
| ************** | 123456789 |
| 987654321 | ********** |

So, "123456789" should not be allowed in secondary_number, if it is already available in primary_number

As well, "987654321" should not be allowed in primary_number, if it already available in secondary_number

Comment: I think that you may use trigger logic for such constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your MySQL version is 8.0.17 or higher then you may use unique multivalued index.

### DEMO

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    val1 INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    val2 INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE vals( (CAST(JSON_ARRAY(val1, val2) AS UNSIGNED ARRAY)) )
    );
```

```
INSERT INTO test (val1, val2) VALUES 
(123,234), (345,456);
```

> ```
> Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
INSERT INTO test (val1, val2) VALUES 
(123,567);
```

> ```
> Duplicate entry '[123, 56' for key 'test.vals'
> ```

```
INSERT INTO test (val1, val2) VALUES 
(678,345);
```

> ```
> Duplicate entry '[345, 67' for key 'test.vals'
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pve_epC-)

Comment: This worked as expected. Thank you Akina

Comment: Akina, I was wondering, is there a way, which can allow any one of the value to be added as NULL.

Comment: @KalpLathia No problems, adjust index expression `CAST(JSON_ARRAY(val1, val2)` accordingly, and, if one of the values is NULL then remove it from the array. For example, you may use not JSON_ARRAY but create an array using sting functions: `CONCAT('[',CONCAT_WS(',',val1, val2),']')`. https://dbfiddle.uk/KPNxxyaF

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question in that way only "pairs" like for example `123456789, 987654321` and `987654321, 123456789` should pre prevented by the unique constraint. If the row `123456789, 987654321` already exists, I assume rows like  `111111111, 987654321` or `123456789,222222222` should still be allowed.

If this is correct so far and if your two columns are numbers, we can use `LEAST` and `GREATEST`:

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable 
  ADD CONSTRAINT uniqueNumbers UNIQUE KEY
  ((LEAST(primary_number, secondary_number)), 
   (GREATEST(primary_number, secondary_number)));
```

This will only prevent such duplicated "pairs".

Try out [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/GovCPhH8)

If this assumption is incorrect and also the other rows should be prevented, I would use a trigger here rather than constraints or use Akina's idea if possible.

Comment: Thanks Jonas, for the solution, but I didn't want just pairs to be checked, but as well individual should also get checked.

Comment: Ok, then I think both a trigger or Akina's idea should be ok. Maybe this answer here will help someone else anyway.